# Doctrine Query Builder CONCAT in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to add CONCAT in ORDERBY function in doctrine 2.

Tried searching in doctrine docs and browsed in web but unable to find a solution for this

Below syntax is throwing an error

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("t");
 $qb->addOrderBy('CONCAT(tep.echtgenootNaam,tep.eigennaam)', $direction);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$qb->addSelect("CONCAT(col1, col2...) AS HIDDEN cat")
  ->orderBy("cat")
```

For this to work, you need to install DoctrineExtensions.

Comment: thanks - this also works with COALESCE and other functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have CONCAT in the addOrder expression. But you can execute something similar:

```
 $qb->addOrderBy('tep.echtgenootNaam', $direction);
 $qb->addOrderBy('tep.eigennaam', $direction);
```